# Type hint for 2D numpy array of multiple possible dtype

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, python-typing

I want to add type hint to a method that accepts a 2D array of following possible types int, unsigned int, float, double. How to add type hint for this?

If it is about only say int, I can write following which works:

```
from typing import NoReturn
from nptyping import NDArray, Shape, Int

def foo(arr: NDArray[Shape["*, *"], Int]) -> NoReturn:
    pass
```

When I try to extend it using `Union` like following, it does not work:

```
from typing import NoReturn, Union
from nptyping import NDArray, Shape, Int, UInt, Float32, Float64

def foo(arr: NDArray[Shape["*, *"], Union[Int, UInt, Float32, Float64]]) -> NoReturn:
    pass
```

I want to avoid using `Any`.

Comment: perhaps not the shortest, but `NDArray[Shape["*, *"], Int] | NDArray[Shape["*, *"], Uint] | ...`?

Comment: @joel - does not work; it gives "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'NDArrayMeta' and 'NDArrayMeta'".  Could this be related python version? I'm on 3.8.5.

Comment: `A | B` is `Union[A, B]` on older versions

Comment: As I said in the original post itself, `Union` of UInt, Int does not work. Let me try this out.

Comment: yes, but I'm asking if moving the `Union` outside the `NDArray` helps