# What is the correct type hint for unsigned integer numpy arrays?

Tags: python, numpy, mypy, python-typing

I want to annotate some functions that receive a numpy array of unsigned integers, do something with them, and then return a numpy array of the same dtype. But I struggle to annotate them. I know how to use `TypeVar` to annotate an array of arbitrary dtype. But the functions do not make sense for floating point values, so I want to restrict the inputs to unsigned integers. I also know, how to restrict the input to a very specific dtype, e.g., with `npt.NDArray[np.ushort]`. But this is too specific. I am searching an intermediate type annotation. But all my ideas (see code below) give errors when I test them on mypy (see errors below).

I have come up with the following `TypeVar`s:

```py
from typing import TypeVar
from typing import Tuple


import numpy as np
import numpy.typing as npt


# Works, but is too unspecific.
T = TypeVar("T", bound=np.generic)


def subsample_array_T(
    x: npt.NDArray[T], grid: Tuple[slice, ...]
) -> npt.NDArray[T]:
    """Takes arrays of any dtype and returns array of same dtype."""
    return x[grid]


# Works, but is too specific.
def subsample_array_ushort(
    x: npt.NDArray[np.ushort], grid: Tuple[slice, ...]
) -> npt.NDArray[np.ushort]:
    """Takes arrays of any dtype and returns array of same dtype."""
    return x[grid]


# Test 1
# error: Missing type parameters for generic type "unsignedinteger"
S = TypeVar("S", bound=np.unsignedinteger)


def subsample_unsigned_S(
    x: npt.NDArray[S], grid: Tuple[slice, ...]
) -> npt.NDArray[S]:
    """Take only arrays of unsigned dtype and return the same dtype."""
    return x[grid]


# Test 2
# error: Type argument "U" of "NDArray" must be a subtype of "generic"
U = TypeVar(
    "U",
    npt.NDArray[np.ubyte],
    npt.NDArray[np.ushort],
    npt.NDArray[np.uintc],
    npt.NDArray[np.uint],
    npt.NDArray[np.ulonglong],
)


def subsample_unsigned_U(
    x: npt.NDArray[U], grid: Tuple[slice, ...]
) -> npt.NDArray[U]:
    """Take only arrays of unsigned dtype and return the same dtype."""
    return x[grid]


# Test 3
# error: TypeVar cannot have both values and an upper bound
V = TypeVar(
    "V",
    npt.NDArray[np.ubyte],
    npt.NDArray[np.ushort],
    npt.NDArray[np.uintc],
    npt.NDArray[np.uint],
    npt.NDArray[np.ulonglong],
    bound=np.generic,
)


# subsequent errors from error above...
def subsample_unsigned_V(
    x: npt.NDArray[V], grid: Tuple[slice, ...]
) -> npt.NDArray[V]:
    """Take only arrays of unsigned dtype and return the same dtype."""
    return x[grid]
```

But they all produce errors in mypy:

```
numpy_unsigned_typing.py:30:24: error: Missing type parameters for generic type "unsignedinteger"  [type-arg]
    S = TypeVar("S", bound=np.unsignedinteger)
                           ^
numpy_unsigned_typing.py: note: In function "subsample_unsigned_U":
numpy_unsigned_typing.py:53: error: Type argument "U" of "NDArray" must be a subtype of "generic"  [type-var]
        x: npt.NDArray[U], grid: Tuple[slice, ...]
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
numpy_unsigned_typing.py: note: At top level:
numpy_unsigned_typing.py:61:1: error: TypeVar cannot have both values and an upper bound  [misc]
    V = TypeVar(
    ^
numpy_unsigned_typing.py: note: In function "subsample_unsigned_V":
numpy_unsigned_typing.py:74:20: error: Variable "numpy_unsigned_typing.V" is not valid as a type  [valid-type]
        x: npt.NDArray[V], grid: Tuple[slice, ...]
                       ^
numpy_unsigned_typing.py:74:20: note: See https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common_issues.html#variables-vs-type-aliases
numpy_unsigned_typing.py:75:18: error: Variable "numpy_unsigned_typing.V" is not valid as a type  [valid-type]
    ) -> npt.NDArray[V]:
                     ^
numpy_unsigned_typing.py:75:18: note: See https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common_issues.html#variables-vs-type-aliases
```

I wanted to use `Union`s of the unsigned datatypes in form of

```py
UnsignedIntegerArray = Union[
    npt.NDArray[np.ubyte],
    npt.NDArray[np.ushort],
    npt.NDArray[np.uintc],
    npt.NDArray[np.uint],
    npt.NDArray[np.ulonglong],
]
```

but then there is no connection between the type annotations of the argument and the return value. Similarly, putting the `Union` only around the dtype and into the `npt.NDArray` does not work as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73696423/10106730).

I guess the most promising way would be to use `Test 1` and add a second `TypeVar` that describes the Bits. At least, the above `UnsignedIntegerArray` union resolves into the following `ndarray[Any, dtype[unsignedinteger[_8Bit]]] | ndarray[Any, dtype[unsignedinteger[_16Bit]]] | ndarray[Any, dtype[unsignedinteger[_32Bit]]] | ndarray[Any, dtype[unsignedinteger[_64Bit]]] | ndarray[Any, dtype[unsignedinteger[_64Bit]]]` . So I would like to do something like:

```py
T = TypeVar("T", np._8Bit, np._16Bit, np._32Bit, np._64Bit)
S = TypeVar("S", bound=np.unsignedinteger[T])
```

But this gives me errors like `Name "np._8Bit" is not defined`. And I do not know how this `np._8Bit` could be resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your third attempt using a type variable with an upper bound of [`np.unsignedinteger`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.25.2/numpy/__init__.pyi#L2940) was almost correct. You were just missing the type argument.

This works:

```py
from typing import TypeVar, Any

import numpy as np
from numpy.typing import NDArray


T = TypeVar("T", bound=np.unsignedinteger[Any])


def subsample_array(
    arr: NDArray[T],
    grid: tuple[slice, ...],
) -> NDArray[T]:
    return arr[grid]


a: NDArray[np.ushort]
out = subsample_array(a, (slice(1), ))
reveal_type(a)
reveal_type(out)
```

Running that code through Mypy *without* using the dedicated [Mypy plugin provided by numpy](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/typing.html#mypy-plugin), gives the following output:

```
note: Revealed type is "numpy.ndarray[Any, numpy.dtype[numpy.unsignedinteger[Any]]]"
note: Revealed type is "numpy.ndarray[Any, numpy.dtype[numpy.unsignedinteger[Any]]]"
```

With the plugin you get this:

```
note: Revealed type is "numpy.ndarray[Any, numpy.dtype[numpy.unsignedinteger[numpy._typing._16Bit]]]"
note: Revealed type is "numpy.ndarray[Any, numpy.dtype[numpy.unsignedinteger[numpy._typing._16Bit]]]"
```

Unfortunately, due to the fact that the Python type systemd does not (yet) support [higher-kinded type variables](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/548), there is no way to cleanly make the type generic in terms of the bit-length as well, but this seems to be sufficient for practical purposes.

Comment: Wouldn't using the `_NBit1` from the definition of [`np.unsignedinteger`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.25.2/numpy/__init__.pyi#L2940) instead of `Any` be even more correct?

Comment: @NiklasNetter No, for two reasons. 1) It is explicitly non-public (i.e. starts with an underscore). 2) It is a type variable and thus its use inside the upper bound of yet another type variable is prohibited (again, because we do not have higher-kinded type variables). So even if you wanted to define your own bit-length type variable like `T1 = TypeVar("T1", bound=npt.NBitBase)` and do `T = TypeVar("T", bound=np.unsignedinteger[T1])` that would not fly (unfortunately).